# fetch recent email from a specific mail address

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using the below google apps script to search recent email from a particular mail address in my inbox. This email has no labels and this script is trying to look at all mails. How to minimize the search for an email and pull out the recent one.

```
function myFunction() 
{  
  var searchterm = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchterm);
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) 
  {
      for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++)
      {
        var mailFrom = messages[i][j].getFrom();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample script?

#### Modification points :

1. For `var threads = GmailApp.search(searchterm);`, `threads[0]` is the latest thread.
2. When `From` is only the particular mail address, it retrieves the mail.
3. When `thread[0]` is processed by loop using `forEach()`, the lower element is newer one.

The script reflected these is as follows.

#### Script :

```
var mailAddress = "myemail@mydomain.com";
var mailFrom;
var thread = GmailApp.search("from:" + mailAddress);
thread[0].getMessages().forEach(function(message) {
  var f = message.getFrom();
  var d = message.getDate();
  if (!~f.indexOf(mailAddress)) return;
  mailFrom = [f, d];
});
```

#### Result :

```
[name <myemail@mydomain.com>, Sat Jan 1 12:34:56 GMT 2017]
```

When the process time is measured, I confirmed that this script brought the improvement about 30% for your sample script. Although I don't know whether this is the best, if this is useful for you, I'm glad.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following search term:

```
var searchterm = "from: myemail@mydomain.com newer:"+parseInt(date/1000);
```

where date is the time value of javascript date variable. For example current date can be calculated as:

```
date = new Date().getTime();
```

This searchterm would return the email threads that are newer than the above date